# Is there a preferred citation style?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we have a unified format for references?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/should-we-have-a-unified-format-for-references)

Should links be given or a PMID is enough? Should the links point to PubMed or directly to the journal article? Is there a care-free citation style in the syntax? If not, can we make/decide on one?

For me, PMID is enough, but then again I don't mind digging in the databases. Not sure about non-proffesionals and/or readers without a way through the pay-walls.

Comment: thanks for bringin this up kate.